# If $B$ is an $(n \times n)$ matrix, and the RREF of $A$, does $\det(A) \neq 0 \Rightarrow \det(B) \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a square matrix $A$ with $\det(A) \neq 0$. And suppose $B$ is the matrix $A$ but in row reduced echelon form. Does it follow that $\det(B) \neq 0$?

Now I am aware of the effects that row operations have on the determinant. However, the thing I am unsure about is multiplying a row by a scalar $\lambda$, which may be $0$ in general. Do we ever need to multiply by $0$ to get a matrix to RREF?

Comment: No, in Gaussian elimination you only multiply by a non-zero scalar.

Comment: @carmichael561 so does the implication hold?

Comment: Yes, if $\det(A)\neq 0$ then $\det(B)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html), it is the invertible matrix theorem. $A$ is invertible if and only if the determinant is not zero, which means $A$ is invertible in your case. By the Invertible matrix theorem, the RREF of an invertible matrix is the identity matrix. So in your case, $B$ is the identity matrix. So it follows that the determinant of $B$ is also not zero.

And for your other question, you can not multiply a row by zero when reducing to RREF. It changes the entire matrix.

Comment: Didn't think of it like that! Thanks so much :)